# InstancedBufferGeometry lookatcamera

Tags: three.js

I'm using Three.js to create a spiral galaxy I've gone down the InstancedBufferGeometry so I can render lots of stars with great performance.

For now, I'm using a plane as my object, the trouble I have is that when I orbit around the galaxy these planes don't look at the camera.

I have tried using the lookat function however that doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how to get InstancedBufferGeometry to look at the camera.

Many thanks in advance.

[image: Galaxy 7.1 million planes]

[image: Orbiting the galaxy, planes not looking at camera]

Comment: It seems like you're looking for [billboarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510020/three-js-glsl-sprite-always-front-to-camera).

Comment: @TheJim01 Billboads not only look at the camera, but they roll with it as well. Sprite rolling is really jarring with galaxy sims, and cannot be disabled because billboard rolling hardcoded into WebGL itself.

Answer (score 3):

The `lookAt` method belongs to [THREE.Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt), and it makes the *entire* object rotate towards a point, not each of its geometry's instances. If you're using `InstancedBufferGeometry`, you could perform these calculations in the vertexShader, but can be computationally expensive, given the quantity of planes you're rendering.

If you're using `InstancedBufferGeometry` for planes only, I recommend you use [THREE.Points](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Points) instead, which is made to automatically generate planes that always look towards the camera, as demonstrated in these examples:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=point#webgl_points_sprites

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=point#webgl_custom_attributes_points

All you'd need to worry about is their positions, and the rotations will  always "billboard" towards the camera without the need of manually calculating rotations.